# Does content loaded in an iframe affect Google Analytics "Page Load Time"?

Tags: iframe, google-analytics

GA is reporting that my page load time is very high, I suspect this is because I load slow-to-load ads in an i-frame, however I am unsure if GA counts content loaded in an iframe when it calculates a "Page Load Time".

Comment: It depends on the browser calling the page as loaded. https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webperf/raw-file/tip/specs/NavigationTiming/Overview.html#processing-model

Hence, probably showing resources from other domains increases load time (yet it allows broser to load simultaneously resources in iframe and resources from your site).

Comment: That's a great diagram, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran some tests and confirmed that loading external content into in iframe (from a slow source) in Chrome/Firefox does indeed increase the "Average Page Load Time" in Google Analytics.