# Google analytics. Iframe actions affects page load

Tags: iframe, google-analytics

Sometimes, according to Google Analytics reports, 1 specific page loads too long, up to 200 seconds. That's too weird, cause that page's loading time is usually between 3-5 seconds. There's an iframe on that page for "async" images uploading. So when we uploaded an image, we noticed that browser console "Page load time" has been increased after each uploading. Google docs shown nothing on this problem, neither do google search.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does content loaded in an iframe affect Google Analytics "Page Load Time"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174505/does-content-loaded-in-an-iframe-affect-google-analytics-page-load-time)